# Primary Key Discriminator persisted with default value in EF Core

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, table-per-hierarchy

### Background

I'm using code first with mapping classes in EF Core at my current project. One of my entities, `Action` is an abstract class that has multiple inheritors `ActionOne`, `ActionTwo`, and `ActionThree`. I'm using TPH with an enum discriminator `ActionType`, which has values starting with 1 and up (it's important for later on).

Entities:

```
public abstract class Action
{
     public DateTime OccurredOn { get; set; }

     public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class ActionOne : Action
{
     public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class ActionTwo : Action
{
     public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class ActionThree : Action
{
     public double Value { get; set; }
}

public enum ActionType
{
     One = 1,
     Two = 2,
     Three = 3
}
```

Mappings:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Action> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Actions", "dbo")
        .HasDiscriminator<ActionType>("ActionType")
        .HasValue<ActionOne>(ActionType.One)
        .HasValue<ActionTwo>(ActionType.Two)
        .HasValue<ActionThree>(ActionType.Three);

    // Indexes 

    // Properties
    builder.Property<ActionType>("ActionType")
        .HasColumnName("ActionType");
    builder.Property(t => t.OccurredOn)
           .HasColumnName("OccurredOn")
           .IsRequired();
    builder.Property<int>("UserID")
        .HasColumnName("UserID");

    // Relationships
    builder.HasOne(t => t.User)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey("UserID")
           .IsRequired();

    // Primary Key
    builder.HasKey("ActionType", "UserID", "OccurredOn");

}
```

### The Issue

**When instantiating a new `Action` entity, adding it to the context and saving it - the persisted record has `ActionType` of 0** (the default value for the enum), which causes a conflict in the primary key and those entities could never be retrieved.

Usage Example:

```
var action1 = new ActionOne
{
    User = user,
    OccurredOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
    Count = count
};

dbContext.Set<Action>().Add(action1);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

### Attempts So Far...

I've tried removing the shadow properties, as well as changing the order of the mapping statements.
I am not interested in exposing the `ActionType` as a property and haven't tried it either.

I am pretty certain that the issue is a double usage of the `ActionType` discriminator as a primary key, but I'm not sure if there's any mapping statements I'm missing to make it work, or it's plainly a bug.

As a workaround, I've added an `ID` identity column and set it the primary key, which solved the problem quick enough.

I figured I will raise the question here to see if any subject matter experts can solve my mystery.